# Css External resources stopped working

Tags: html, css, resources, loading, external

Everything was fine until a couple of hours ago, where the external resources of my css stoped being loaded...
i thought it might be a connection issue so i uploaded it to an ftp server with no successful results...

as external resources i have an image & fonts from google
These resources are not being loaded

```
.body{
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/xmDujXb.jpg);
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

[Fiddle with html & css](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeStardust/T5LmQ/)

[Live website](http://alunos.thelisbonschoolofdesign.com/miguel-pires/)

I don't know if its relevant but i'm using brackets to code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the `.` in `.body` and it should work.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T5LmQ/1/)

Comment: Don't worry it happens :-)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `.body`

its not a class

just use

```
body{
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/xmDujXb.jpg);
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

if correct please select as best answer :D